# Mount GPT Partitioned Drive In Linux

Tags: ubuntu, gpt

I have a windows 8 hard drive slaved to my Ubuntu box right now and I'm having problems mounting. When I go to mount, the shell tells me that the device doesn't exist but I can bring it up and see the partition via fdisk.

Whats going on?

Comment: If it is really a disk with GPT, then you should use gdisk, not fdisk. Please post the output of either fdisk -l or gdsik /dev/sdX, whichever yields output.

Comment: Also post the output of `ls /dev/sdX` (where `/dev/sdX` is the identifier for the disk in question).